# RethinkDB - retrieving data by timestamp: Not a TIME pseudotype?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, rethinkdb

I create timestamp using JavaScript's Date:

```
let timestamp = Date.now()
```

So I would timestamps like this:

```
1574651336667
1574651408395
1574651361751
```

When I want to retrieve the rows that were inserted on the 25th:

```
r.table("users").filter(
    r.row("timestamp").day().eq(25)
).run(conn, callback)
```

But I get this error:

```
Not a TIME pseudotype: `1574651336667` in:\nr.table(\"users\").filter(function(var_0) {
```

what does it mean?

What should I do to retrieve the data correctly with timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `r.epochTime` function to convert those timestamp to the rethink date-time format:

```
r.table("users").filter(function(f){
   return r.epochTime(f("timestamp").div(1000)).day().eq(25)
})
```

You can also consider using `r.now()` when you are inserting the data. So that you don't have to convert anymore.